# Unable to run the Watson Dialog tool locally with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson, watson-dialog

I have installed the Watson Dialog tool on my environment and try to run the app.js app.

Unfortunately , it does not run and I get the following messages :
can you help ? Thank you 
PCMacBook-Pro:dialog-tool-master philippecomte$ node app.js
/Users/philippecomte/Documents/ALGE2016/WATSON_SERVICES_BLUEMIX/Dialog_Services/dialog-tool-master/config/express.js:26
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
    at module.exports (/Users/philippecomte/Documents/ALGE2016/WATSON_SERVICES_BLUEMIX/Dialog_Services/dialog-tool-master/config/express.js:26:6)
    at Object. (/Users/philippecomte/Documents/ALGE2016/WATSON_SERVICES_BLUEMIX/Dialog_Services/dialog-tool-master/app.js:20:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
PCMacBook-Pro:dialog-tool-master philippecomte$

Answer (score 0):

Followed the steps below and it worked : 
download & unzip
enter directory with unzipped files
run npm install
run npm start

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but there is a detailed guide to running the tool locally on the github repository for the dialog-tool.

You can find it here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dialog-tool

Comment: You should include the fundamental info from your link in your answer. You never know if that url will be valid in a month.